# Select "All" radio button option in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button

I am trying to create a shiny app which has radio buttons and allows a user to select an "All" button which shows all of the data prior to this filter.

I have posted my full code below and here is a link to the [current live app](https://mike-maieli.shinyapps.io/SuperBowlBoxes/).

As seen in the live app, I would like to have users be able to select the "All" radio button under quarter which would show all of the data, regardless of quarter. Currently the other options under quarter work as planned.

After finding a few other similar posts, I tried to set up if else functions within the filtering in the server portion of the code and created the choice within the radio button in the ui portion of the code, but had no luck with the output. I am also struggling to find out if there are other changes I need to make to the "choices" part of the ui code.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes)

score_data <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikemaieli/superbowlsquares/master/superbowlscores.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("yearInput",
                        "Year",
                        min = 1960,
                        max = 2020,
                        value = c(1967, 2019),
                        sep = "",
                        ticks = 10),
            radioButtons("quarterInput", "Quarter",
                         choices = c("All" = "???",
                                     "1st quarter" = "1",
                                     "2nd quarter" = "2",
                                     "3rd quarter" = "3",
                                     "4th quarter" = "4",
                                     "Overtime" = "5"),
                         selected = "1"),
            ),
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput("heatmap"),
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$heatmap <- 
    renderPlot({
      digit_counts <- score_data %>% 
        mutate(afc_digit = afc_total_score %% 10, nfc_digit = nfc_total_score %% 10) %>% 
        select(year, superbowl, quarter, afc_digit, nfc_digit) %>% 
        mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
        filter(year >= input$yearInput[1],
               year <= input$yearInput[2],
               quarter == input$quarterInput) %>% 
        group_by(afc_digit, nfc_digit) %>% 
        summarize(occurances = n())

      ggplot(digit_counts, aes( x = afc_digit,
                                y = nfc_digit)) +
        geom_tile(aes(fill = occurances), color = "black") +
        geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent((occurances/sum(digit_counts$occurances)))),
                  color = "white") +
        scale_fill_gradient(low = "gray75", high = "dodgerblue4", na.value = "white") +
        scale_x_discrete(position = "top",
                         limits = c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")) +
        scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"))) +
        labs(x = "AFC",
             y = "NFC") +
        theme_minimal() + 
        theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
              legend.position = "none") +
        geom_vline(xintercept=c(.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5), color="black", size = .3) +
        geom_hline(yintercept=c(.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5), color="black", size = .3)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `server` function like below.

```
  server <- function(input, output, session) { digit_counts <- reactive({
    if (input$quarterInput == "???") {
    score_data %>%
      mutate(afc_digit = afc_total_score %% 10, nfc_digit = nfc_total_score %% 10) %>%
      select(year, superbowl, quarter, afc_digit, nfc_digit) %>%
      mutate_all(as.character) %>%
      group_by(afc_digit, nfc_digit) %>%
      summarize(occurances = n())
    } else {
   score_data %>%
      mutate(afc_digit = afc_total_score %% 10, nfc_digit = nfc_total_score %% 10) %>%
      select(year, superbowl, quarter, afc_digit, nfc_digit) %>%
      mutate_all(as.character) %>%
      filter(year >= input$yearInput[1],
             year <= input$yearInput[2],
             quarter == input$quarterInput) %>%
      group_by(afc_digit, nfc_digit) %>%
      summarize(occurances = n())
}})

  output$heatmap <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(digit_counts(), aes( x = afc_digit,
                            y = nfc_digit)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = occurances), color = "black") +
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent((occurances/sum(digit_counts()$occurances)))),
              color = "white") +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "gray75", high = "dodgerblue4", na.value = "white") +
    scale_x_discrete(position = "top",
                     limits = c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")) +
    scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"))) +
    labs(x = "AFC",
         y = "NFC") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "none") +
    geom_vline(xintercept = c(.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5), color = "black", size = .3) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = c(.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5), color = "black", size = .3)
})}
```

Here I understood like when you select `All` as your choice then no filter should apply on the data. So i have removed the filter condition in `if` condition.

Comment: Ah, perfect! I was trying to use the `if` condition within `renderPlot` function, but your solution works great. Thanks!